# Hide username completely while the machine is auto logging in

Tags: windows, security, privacy-policy

I have a unique requirement, I have setup a PC which would auto login to a particular user id say 'autologinuser', when ever we switch on the PC it would automatically logs into 'autologinuser' as configured.

During the login, it would show which using is getting logged in with welcome text under it.

I would like to hide the user name and don't want to visible during auto login process, only windows text should be visible.

Can this be possible?

Thanks & Regards,

-Anil Katta

Answer (score 0):

Looks like windows operating system don't provide this feature at this point of time, and there is no specific registry to do so.

May be this feature good to expect in future releases.